# Get top 3 from a table in MySQL C#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core

I have a table that looks like this and changes pretty often:

[image: Picture of the table]

I'd like to order it by top 3 by flowers so it looks like this:

```
5                                                              
3                                                                  
1
```

This is the code I have:

```
public class tableName3
{
 // public ulong UserId { get; set; }
    public int Flowers { get; set; }
}



public static List<tableName3> getFlowers(ulong serverid)
{
    var result = new List<tableName3>();
    var database = new Database("DataBase");
    var str = string.Format("SELECT * FROM `{0}` ORDER BY flowers DESC LIMIT 3", serverid);
    var tableName = database.FireCommand(str);
                             // modified
    while (tableName.Read())
    {
        var floweramount = (int)tableName["flowers"];
        result.Add(new tableName3
        {
            Flowers = floweramount,
        });
    }
    database.CloseConnection();
    return result;
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
    var lb = Database.getFlowers(id);
    Console.WriteLine(lb.FirstOrDefault().Flowers.ToString());
```

But it returns only 5.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: It is probably returning the id # of the top row (5), which is the `FirstOrDefault` when sorting by flowers in descending order...

Comment: Try `Console.WriteLine(lb.Count());` - that will tell you *how many* rows were returned, rather than the `floweramount` of the top row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using lb.FirstOrDefault() which will return the first [0] element from your collection. You can iterate through it with for/foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code returns a list of tableName3, you need to loop on the results and build your output looking at the three elements returned

With linq is just a line of code

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ",lb.Select(x => X.Flowers.ToString()));
```